# How is this possible? Animated JPG in Google Image Search results

Tags: javascript, image, google-image-search

I was searching for "Jaguar Rims" in google image results. I clicked on a plain photo that had no site logos or insignia on it. But after-the-click a promo of "39 photos" and the site address was populated onto the image.

How did they do this? I would like to re-create this effect

Was it an animated JPEG? Or rendered with Javascript? Keep in mind, I find this interesting only because it is happening within Google Image Search results.

This is the [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=939&q=jaguar%20rims&oq=jaguar%20rims&gs_l=img.3..0l7j0i5l3.2038.3159.0.3268.11.8.0.1.1.1.245.727.0j3j1.4.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.60.img..7.4.488.2DsCJzd9GHY) I performed (it's 3rd image from the left but this could change).

Here is the image:
http://preview.netcarshow.com/Jaguar-XKR-2010-1600-21.jpg

Comment: I don't see any animation

Answer (score 0):

It's not animating. The two images were likely cached at different times by google and the image publisher changed the image in-between those times.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the only way is with php. You can check the referer header and display a different image accordingly. This is how you check the header in php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you see icon data:image/jpeg;.......    size: 259x194
2. After you click on it, you get similar image but scaled up:
   https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1p2CI2vcgxkxMr8j8L0HfdmEBv_ggGM8RAri4-FWP9B0ENj9vDw
3. After part of second, you get full image, but becouse its big and it need time to load and resize, there is short time then you see #2 image.
   http://preview.netcarshow.com/Jaguar-XKR-2010-1600-21.jpg

.#2 and #1 is same image, but without #2 part, seeing big image should take longer i guess after you click on icon.

So basically it is animation from 3 frames. icon -> bigger icon -> big image.

p.s. Google made icon from this one, that can be found in same site:
http://img2.netcarshow.com/Jaguar-XKR_2010_1024x768_wallpaper_21.jpg